# How to express matrix multiplication and columnwise summation mathematically?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have matrix $\bf A$ and $\bf B$, both are of the same size.

I perform elementwise multiplication between $\bf A$ and $\bf B$.

Then I need to sum up column-wise the resultant matrix.

How to show it mathematically?

I am doing like this

$\sum {\bf A}\odot {\bf B}$

where, $\odot$ stands for elementwise multiplication and The $\sum$ operator sums up column-wise, i.e., for any given column, the row elements are added.

Am I using the right syntax?

Comment: Thinking out aloud, isn’t the result just $\mathrm{diag}(A^TB)$?

Comment: So at the end you have a $n \times 1$ matrix if the initial ones have $n \times m$ for dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}b_{11} & a_{12}b_{12} & \cdots &a_{1m}b_{1m} \\ a_{21}b_{21} & a_{22}b_{22} & \cdots & a_{2m}b_{2m}\\ \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n1}b_{n1} & a_{n2}b_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nm}b_{nm}\end{bmatrix} $$
and then you want to sum the rows to obtain
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}b_{11} + a_{21}b_{21} + \cdots +a_{n1}b_{n1} \\ a_{12}b_{12} + a_{22}b_{22} + \cdots + a_{n2}b_{n2}\\ \vdots  \\ a_{1m}b_{1m} + a_{2m}b_{2m} + \cdots + a_{nm}b_{nm}\end{bmatrix}^T.$$
Thus the $k$th column is given by $a_{1k}b_{1}+a_{2k}b_{2k}+\cdots +a_{nk}b_{nk}$. Does this formula ring a bell? (Think dot product.)

Comment: no I do not want this, I just want the opposite. a11b11+a21b21+.....

Comment: Ok, edited, but the idea still holds. This can be expressed in terms of dot products.